# What's the limit, if any, on how many ports can be forwarded on an ASUS router running the AsusWRT stock firmware?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, asuswrt

What's the limit, if any, on how many ports can be forwarded on an ASUS router running the AsusWRT stock firmware? If router-specific, I'm interested in the [ASUS RT-AX88U AX6000](https://smile.amazon.com/RT-AX88U-Dual-Band-Aiprotection-Lifetime-Compatible/dp/B07HM6KJN8) and the [ASUS ROG Rapture GT-AX11000](https://smile.amazon.com/ASUS-ROG-Rapture-GT-AX11000-AX11000-Tri-Band-10-Gigabit-WiFi-Router-Aiprotection-Lifetime-Security-by-Trend-Micro-Aimesh-Compatible-for-Mesh-WIFI-System-Next-Gen-Wifi-6-Wireless-802-11Ax-8-X-Giga/dp/B07MRD1LDZ).

Comment: I've not used it, but I imagine if you use a DMZ - all of them.  I doubt that there are any real obstacles to large number of forwards as they are not very resource intensive.

Comment: @davidgo: Technically yes, but I've had a few routers (mainly D-Link) which had a set limit of e.g. 20 "virtual servers" in their config UI, so it's a fair question.

Comment: @user1686 Its absolutely a fair question. Of-course, with AsusWRT you are not limited to the GUI...  The way I understand it asuswrt is similar to ddwrt.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.snbforums.com/threads/port-forwarding-limitation.35382/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919191033/https://www.snbforums.com/threads/port-forwarding-limitation.35382/)):

> - Asuswrt-Merlin firmware limits port redirects to 128 port forwards
> - [ASUS RT-AC51U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC51U/) stock Asuswrt firmware limits to 32 port forwards

I'm guessing that the limit on port forwards for
the [ASUS RT-AX88U AX6000](https://smile.amazon.com/RT-AX88U-Dual-Band-Aiprotection-Lifetime-Compatible/dp/B07HM6KJN8) and the [ASUS ROG Rapture GT-AX11000](https://smile.amazon.com/ASUS-ROG-Rapture-GT-AX11000-AX11000-Tri-Band-10-Gigabit-WiFi-Router-Aiprotection-Lifetime-Security-by-Trend-Micro-Aimesh-Compatible-for-Mesh-WIFI-System-Next-Gen-Wifi-6-Wireless-802-11Ax-8-X-Giga/dp/B07MRD1LDZ) stock Asuswrt firmware is between 32 and 128 ports, since [ASUS RT-AC51U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC51U/) is older and the Asuswrt-Merlin firmware typically extends Asuswrt's abilities.

Comment: I can confirm the limit in EVERY AsusWRT stock firmware I have ever seen (about 15 different models) was 32. I think it is the same for all models. AsusWRT-Merlin raises that to 128 in the GUI (for all models as far as I know) and you can set even more via the command-line if you really need it.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks, good to know!